# Execute HttpPost with google token in android is not fetching JSON data

Tags: android, http-post, google-oauth, access-token, httpentity

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("MyWebsiteURL");
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key="+token));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            String json = sb.toString();
            Log.i("JSON", json);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i think we can not pass parameters in URL using post method..

Comment: @Prag's then how can I establish connection with mywebsite using google token?

Comment: @Prag's sorry.. URL is like Mywebsite/auth/auth2_login

Comment: use BasicNameValuePair for passing token

Comment: @Prag's this is the syntax for BasicNameValuePair --- its got two parameters how can I pass just token.      List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

Comment: @Prag'sシ this is the error I'm receiving. Could you explain me about this. '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/login">POST&nbsp;/login</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at todoed-preseed.rhcloud.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>'

Comment: it means your code is correct and you are receiving output from your server side....but you are passing wrong credentials to it

Answer (score 1):

First you cannot pass parameter like this in http post, use below code for your use, there might be some compilation error as am not using and IDE for checking code which am posting, main point is to show you how to pass post parameters using http post, which is by using NameValuePairs, please adjust your url accordingly

```
        try {
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "12345"));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            String json = sb.toString();
            Log.i("JSON", json);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: HttpPost parameter = String representing your POST's destination. I want to make HttpPost request to my website.

Comment: new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"), pass whatever website you want to refer, while creating new HttpPost object.

Comment: I have problem with new HttpPost().setEntity() parameter. not with HttpPost object. I want to post this ("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key="+token) to my website.

Comment: Thats am trying to help you with, key is a parameter for you, and i just mentioned to you the way to post it !!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Difference between [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) and [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_(HTTP)#Request_methods) method...

In GET METHOD you can pass data with URL....
but in POST method you can not pass data with URL... you have to pass it as entity.........
Do the following for Passing Data To the URL

Try This..

```
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(WEBSITE_URL);
        try{    
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            //use this to pass variables while using POST method
            // add an HTTP variable and value pair
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key name","key value")); 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key name","key value"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key name","key value"));

            // passing data to the URL
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            //do the following..

           }
```

For your solution You should pass

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key",token));
```

Where,

```
 Key - variable or key you defined in Your page (Backend side)     
 token = is a value which you want to pass..........
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the posting for authentication. This will return a HttpResponse containing the access token
in which you will use when you do a HttpGet request.

```
  try {
        Log.i(tag, "Starting doHTTPPost");
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("KEY", "VALUE"));

        /* EXAMPLE of pairs */
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id","theGreatSecret12345"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "purple"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "asjdf098732hkndfa"));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("The API Server you want to access");
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpResponse apiResponse = response;
        String resultFromServerAsAString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.i(tag, "Response statusCode : "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        Log.i(tag, "Response StatusLine : "+response.getStatusLine());
        Log.i(tag, "Ending doHTTPPost");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```